# How can I close the application when any form is closed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have multiple forms in my VB.NET application. How do I make it so that any form I close will terminate the application?

Comment: thank you very much for your replies. unfortunately, they do not answer the question. there must be some setting i can tweak before compiling that will make the program close when any form is closed.

Comment: @alex - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966695/how-can-i-close-the-application-when-any-form-is-closed/966701#966701) should work perfectly. Unfortunately you cant tweak a compiler setting but doing this will get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(VS.71).aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably put your `Application.Exit()` call in the `OnClosed` method of the forms.

Comment: Mmm, wouldn't OnClosed be more appropriate?

Comment: R. Bemrose: Probably. OnClosing was the only event that I could remember off the top of my head. I don't spend nearly enough time in WinForms.

Comment: I don't either, I just remember that onClosing is when you can cancel a close, meaning that the form is still around and can be accessed.  I also can't remember if it's OnClose or OnClosed.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a base class Form from which all of your Forms inherit.  In that particular class you can override the OnClosed method and call Application.Exit to quit the program.  Now the closing of any form in your application which derives from this Form, will cause the application to Exit

```
Public MustInherit Class MyForm
  Inherits Form

  Protected Overrides Sub OnClose(args As EventArgs)
    Application.Exit()
  End Sub
End Class
```